# Attach certificate file to request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

In Python, if I want to attach a certificate to a request using the `requests` library, I can do it like this:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```

Is there a way I can do this if I have the certificate file contents as a string or bytes? I have this stored in AWS parameter store and I don't want to save it as a file in the system to be able to use it.